# How to make property editable in PropertyGrid?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, winrt-component

I'm developing a custom control for Windows Store App. This control has a property of type MyPoint:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterPointProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CenterPoint",
        typeof(MyPoint), typeof(MapControl), new PropertyMetadata(new GeoPoint(0, 0), CenterPointPropertyChanged));

    public MyPoint CenterPoint {
        get { return (MyPoint)GetValue(CenterPointProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CenterPointProperty, value); }
    }
```

MyPoint is a regular class, not DependecyObject descendant.
When user use my control in Visual Studio, user can't edit this property via PropertyGrid.

If MyPoint is DependencyObject there will be the "New..." button in the PropertyGrid. But I don't need DependencyObject descendant.

As I know, there is no TypeConverter or analogue is .Net for Windows Store Apps.

Is there some way to make this property editable?